# Pass in object in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to render a partial in my application.html.erb. The partial originates from the Product folder "products/categories". When I try to insert a partial in the application.html.erb, like below, I get undefined local variable or method `categories' for #<#:0x007fcfa35c9c78>. Any help is greatly appreciated.

application.html.erb

```
<%= render 'products/categories', locals: { categories: categories }%>
```

products/_categories.html.erb

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
 <li><%= category %></li>
<% end %>
```

products_controller.rb

```
 def categories
  @categories = ProductCategory.all
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your render you have

```
locals: { categories: categories }
```

which will define `categories` in your partial

But in that partial you are referring to `@categories`.

You will still have access to all instance variables in the partial even if you don't pass them as locales.

Also be aware that controller methods aren't automatically available to views.

You need to also write `helper_method :categories` in the controller or move the method to the helpers file.

Although it's probably not a good idea to name local variables the same as methods, so you should rename the method to `get_categories` or something.

Comment: what I ended up doing is just creating a helper method and reference it in the _categories.html.erb. I couldn't get anything else to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing locale as `locals: { categories: categories }` as local variable and in view you calling instance variable @categories which will not get in that view.
try to pass locale as `locals: { categories: @categories }` and in view use

```
<% categories.each do |category| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow: Never use a instance variable in a partial.

Pass variables into the partial instead. You can use the `render` shorthand instead of `render partial`, which makes it a bit easier to read.

`<%= render "products/categories", categories: @categories %>`

```
# app/views/products/categories
<% categories.each do |category| %>
 <li><%= category %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks but i couldn't get it to work used helper method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `partial:` if wanna pass params to partial. Also, you have miss typo in `locals`, make it `@categories`.

```
<%= render partial: 'products/categories', locals: { categories: @categories }%>
```

and loop it without `@`

```
<% categories.each do |category| %>
 <li><%= category %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks but i couldn't get it to work used helper method instead.